# Postgres Drop constraints order

Tags: postgresql

When dropping constraints from a postgres table , How to know the safest order to drop  the constraints. Like ,
  1) The foreign key constraints can be dropped first [as they have to be droppped before primary key constraint]

Then the order of removing the constraints can be in any order . like check constraint, unique constraint, not nulls, default ,   primary key constraints . Am I correct

Comment: If you drop constraints for a **single** table the order is actually irrelevant. And if you use `CASCADE` then the order is also irrelevant when dropping constraints from multiple tables

Comment: May I know the case which will invalidate the above order if cascade is not used

Comment: Actually am super excited to know the cases , can you please reply @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No constraint on a PostgreSQL table depends on another constraint on the same table, so the order does not matter here.

The only dependency between constraints is the dependency of a foreign key on the primary or unique key on the target table.

So you can either remove all foreign key constraints first and then all other constraints, or you can use `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ... CASCADE` which will automatically drop all dependent constraints, then you don't have to care about the order at all.

Comment: That really helped . Thanks :)